# Django Rest Framework: Different Validations for HTTP POST and PUT

Tags: python, validation, django-rest-framework

I have a custom validation function in my `DataSerliazer` which checks two parameters (mrange , mthreshold). The validation function checks that only one of the parameters needs to be set while posting.

```
class DataSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    emails = serializers.ListField(child = serializers.EmailField())
    class Meta:
        model = AIData
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'created', 'username', 'token',
                  'expression','key','threshold' ,'evaluator', 'range','emails','metric_name', 'status')

   def validate(self,attrs):
mrange = attrs.get("metric_range")
        mthreshold  = attrs.get("metric_threshold")
    if (mrange == None or mrange == " ") and (mthreshold == None or mthreshold == " "):
            raise serializers.ValidationError({'error': 'Cannot have both range and threshold empty'})
        elif mrange != None and mthreshold != None:
            raise serializers.ValidationError({'error': 'Cannot set both range and threshold'})
```

In my views.py file

```
@api_view(['GET','PUT', 'DELETE'])
def ai_detail(request, token, id):
        ai = None
        try:
                ai = AIData.objects.get(id=id)
        except AIData.DoesNotExist:
                return Response(status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)

        if request.method == 'GET':
                serializer = DataSerializer(ai)
                if serializer.data['token'] == token:
                        return Response(serializer.data)
                else:
                        return Response({'error': 'Not allowed to access'}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

        elif request.method == 'PUT':
                serializer = AlAnotherSerializerMethod(alert, data=request.data, partial=True)
                if serializer.is_valid():
                      // updating code
```

Currently,  I have to write anthor `AIAnotherSerializerMethod` so that, it does not implicitly call the validate function in DataSerializer. This is to avoid checking the 2 parameters during object creation. Once the object is created , I dont want to check the same function anymore. Is there a neater way of doing the same ? I would preferably avoid the need for writing 2 Serializers for the same model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass [`context` data](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#including-extra-context) to the serializer which could include the request itself.

You can access the context anytime anywhere in the serializer by calling self.context.

This solution does makes it easier to provide contextual data without overriding the `__init__`.

Answer (score 0):

The rest-framework library doesn't have anything like that as far as I know.

The way I do it is to overide the `__init__` and add your own variable to check this.

```
class DataSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    emails = serializers.ListField(child = serializers.EmailField())
    class Meta:
        model = AIData
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'created', 'username', 'token',
                  'expression','key','threshold' ,'evaluator', 'range','emails','metric_name', 'status')

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(DataSerializer, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self._request_method = kwargs.get('request_method', 'GET')

    def validate(self,attrs):
        if self._request_method == 'GET':
            # GET logic
        elif self._request_method in ('PUT', 'POST'):
            # Put or Post logic
```

And then i'd use it like this:

```
serializer = DataSerializer(ai, request_method=request.method)
```